# Swing plugin for Eclipse Juno 4.2

Tags: java, eclipse, swing, eclipse-plugin, eclipse-juno

I updated my Eclipse from Indigo to Juno 4.2, but I don't find the "Swing Plugin" for Eclipse.

I need the swing in Eclipse, I don't like NetBeans, so, there's some way to use Swing in Eclipse?

Where I can find that for download? How add Swing to Eclipse Juno 4.2?

Comment: What "Swing plugin"? Swing is part of the core Java libraries and so no plugins are needed.

Comment: Hey man, stay calm. This is just a self-answered question, it will help a lot of people, doesn't matter if other people answer this question by another way, in another questions.

Answer (score 17, accepted):

It's easy to solve this problem, just follow these tips:

1. Open your "Eclipse 4.2" (Eclipse Juno).
2. Go to "Help" tab.
3. Click in "Install new Software..."
4. A new window will appear, in the field "type or select a site" put: "http://dl.google.com/eclipse/inst/d2wbpro/latest/4.2" and press "Enter".
5. Select all available updates and click "Next".
6. Now just proceed the installation. Later you will need restart the Eclipse. Do that.

Good luck! :)

Comment: The link is outdated